# Minimum amount of PII (personally identifiable information) to ding credit

Tags: united-states, credit-score, medical-bill

If I give a Dr. my past address (property that is either now a rental where I am the property manager or a house I no longer own), date of birth, age etc. and a copy of my passport, but don't give them my social, can they still report an unpaid bill to my credit?

Specifically, I am trying to answer this question: Without giving fake details (and maybe that's the only option here), what information do I have to withhold to make it impossible to hit my credit with an unpaid, post visit bill?

I am NOT asking how to commit medical billing fraud! I do my best to ensure I am paying the entire bill onsite and give the office explicit details verbally and sometimes written (via email) that I cannot be post billed due to constant international travel. I am aware that I could pay for a mail forwarding/scanning service and am NOT asking for that advice. Everyone else (except the medical community) has been able to work with me without that service. However, I have had a particular office that lifted an old address off my ID and attempted to bill me later for "coding error". Of course, this bounced around for 5 months. Luckily that office would not report to credit for 6 months. Would like to avoid this situation going forward.

Comment: While you're not aiming to commit medical billing fraud yourself, any answer provided to this question could be used by others for that purpose, so I'm not sure how appropriate it would be for this site. However, this seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/66378); perhaps it would be better to ask how to confirm medical bills have been paid in full without regular access to USPS mail.

Comment: @CactusCake True... but as community members is that really our problem? I suppose someone will vote to close if that's the case. For me it's one of those situations where if I wanted to actually commit medical billing fraud, the solution seems obvious. Just get a fake ID, fake social and never visit the same Dr. twice. But, that's not my goal at all. It's more to force certain offices to own up to their own mistakes.

Comment: I'd like to add, that some providers have allowed me to over-pay by as much as 100% to avoid this situation. Others won't allow that.

Comment: Yes they can report without SSN, and almost certainly with a prior address. But aside from the provider waiting, the main scorers are now reducing the 'ding' for medical debt problems, which (logically enough) are less predictive than other debts; see https://www.statnews.com/2017/07/11/credit-score-medical-debt/

Answer (score 2):

Find a doctor that has an online presence for billing. Most of the doctors I work with have this. You can check periodically. You can also have the system trigger an email alert when a bill/report is posted.

Even in cases when I get a bill via snail mail after the visit, I can track the amount via my insurance companies website. The doctors office or other medical service providers submission to the insurance company and the resulting EOB (Explanation of Benefits) gives me all the numbers I need to settle any balance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a service from someone, it is your responsibility to pay for the service.  You are attempting to avoid being penalized by the service provider because you have nonstandard arrangements, but you have no legitimate grounds to do so.  Explaining to them that it is a hardship for you to deal with payment issues after you leave the premises or even sending them instructions to this effect does not change this.

If you want an ironclad guarantee that a particular service provider will comply with your payment terms, then you will need them to sign a legally binding agreement with you to that effect.

You may find this is more of a headache than a forwarding service, a trusted friend or family member other options that allow you to respond to these issues more promptly.

Lastly, I would advise you to be prepared to adapt.  Just because you have only found one service provider that is not flexible enough, does not mean there are not more out there.  In particular, the government or anyone offering something in high demand can be very unaccommodating.

Comment: You clearly didn't read my question and are providing opinions instead of facts.

"I am aware that I could pay for a mail forwarding/scanning service and am NOT asking for that advice"
...and...
"I do my best to ensure I am paying the entire bill onsite and give the office explicit details verbally and sometimes written (via email) that I cannot be post billed due to constant international travel." The Dr. is agreeing to service me based on those terms. If anyone isn't upholding their responsibility it is not me. Again, opinions about morality - not answers.

Comment: Agreed about adapting... btw: "You're going to have to adapt" would have been a legit answer. But that's not what you said. I think I was pretty clear why I downvoted your ill founded legal/moral opinion. If you disagree, please point out how I'm wrong.

Comment: @maplemale Revised.

Comment: I think that's better, though looking for more of a direct answer to my PII question, your answer is NOT downvote worthy ihop. Just like you said, not really the answer I'm looking for!  And, not really 100% direct answer to a direct question. I guess that's OK for certain questions like this however. Thanks for your answer!